# How to calculate total of product for every product with lambda in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables for this case.
[image]

I want to bring total piece of product ( sum(ProductNumber) ) for every product in this code but I have no idea for piece.

```
CimriContext context = new CimriContext();
    public ICollection<StockDto.StockHeader> FillDataGrid(int userCompanyId)
    {
        return context.Stocks.Where(s => s.UserCompany.UserCompanyId.Equals(userCompanyId)).
            Select(s => new StockDto.StockHeader()
            {
                StockId = s.StockId,
                StockName = s.StockName,
                Piece = // how can I here ?
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: so i am assuming the `product_stockid` is the foreign key to `stockId`?

Comment: @Aominè Yes, Your comment is true

Answer (score 0):

you can get the list of the products depending on the where you want  , then use linq sum just like this one

```
var productsList = context.Products.Where(
       s =>s.UserCompany.UserCompanyId.Equals(userCompanyId)).ToList();

 var totalOfPiece = productsList.sum(m=>m.Piece) 
//or replace Piece with int value 

    return context.Stocks.Where(s => s.UserCompany.UserCompanyId.Equals(userCompanyId)).
                Select(s => new StockDto.StockHeader()
                {
                    StockId = s.StockId,
                    StockName = s.StockName,
                    Piece = totalOfPiece // total of Pieces here 
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find all the matching records in your `productTransaction` collection and then perform the summation of the `ProductNumber`.

```
 Piece = context.ProductTransactions.Where(x => x.product_stockid == s.stockId)
                                    .Sum(x => x.ProductNumber);
```